# How to obtain city name in case when the google maps api address components does not provide it

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I was working on Google geocoding api using [angular-maps](https://angular-maps.com/).

I see that for some places on the map, we do not get the actual city name, instead we get the sub-locality name in the `locality` section of address components.

Please check an example of such a situation below. I get the value `Kesklinna` for `locality` section, where the city name is supposed to be `Tallinn`.

```
[
   {
      "long_name":"1",
      "short_name":"1",
      "types":[
         "street_number"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Suur Rannavärav",
      "short_name":"Suur Rannavärav",
      "types":[
         "route"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Kesklinn",
      "short_name":"Kesklinn",
      "types":[
         "political",
         "sublocality",
         "sublocality_level_1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Kesklinna",
      "short_name":"Kesklinna",
      "types":[
         "locality",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Harju maakond",
      "short_name":"Harju maakond",
      "types":[
         "administrative_area_level_1",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Estonia",
      "short_name":"EE",
      "types":[
         "country",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"10414",
      "short_name":"10414",
      "types":[
         "postal_code"
      ]
   }
]
```

While if we place the marker just around 100 meters away from this place, I am getting the correct city of `Tallinn`.

```
[
   {
      "long_name":"10",
      "short_name":"10",
      "types":[
         "street_number"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Rannamäe tee",
      "short_name":"Rannamäe tee",
      "types":[
         "route"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Kesklinn",
      "short_name":"Kesklinn",
      "types":[
         "political",
         "sublocality",
         "sublocality_level_1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Tallinn",
      "short_name":"Tallinn",
      "types":[
         "locality",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Harju maakond",
      "short_name":"Harju maakond",
      "types":[
         "administrative_area_level_1",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"Estonia",
      "short_name":"EE",
      "types":[
         "country",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {
      "long_name":"10133",
      "short_name":"10133",
      "types":[
         "postal_code"
      ]
   }
]
```

Is this some kind of bug on the google maps geocoder? Or is this expected?
How will I be able to determine the correct city name from the marker location?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a data issue. Have a look at the boundaries of Tallinn in Google Maps

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tallinn,+Estonia/@59.420911,24.7681033,12.89z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x46929499df5616bf:0x400b36d18fc6270!8m2!3d59.4369608!4d24.7535747

The first address is clearly situated inside the Tallinn's polygon

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DSuur%2520Rannav%25E4rav%25201%252C%2520Kesklinna%252C%2520Estonia

I tried to find a locality with name Kesklinna, but it doesn't exist

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DKesklinna%252C%2520Estonia

There is only sublocality with name Kesklinn that forms part of Tallinn city

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kesklinn,+Tallinn,+Estonia/@59.4827351,24.6316448,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x469294b4763fb4c7:0x500b36d18fc70f0!8m2!3d59.4268518!4d24.7595564

This suggests that address 'Suur Rannavärav 1, Kesklinna, Estonia' is broken.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Suur+Rannav%C3%A4rav+1,+Kesklinn,+Kesklinna,+10414+Harju+maakond,+Estonia/@59.4435038,24.7454318,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46929364f1572a67:0x998f646719ef7e67!8m2!3d59.4435038!4d24.7476205

You can use Send feedback link in bottom right corner of maps to report a bad data to Google.

As a workaround you can use reverse geocoding with coordinate of your address and result type locality

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.44350379999999%2C24.7476205&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This will return 'Tallinn, Estonia' as expected.

I hope this helps!